# Let $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda), Y \sim \text{Exp}(\mu),$ and $Z = X/Y$. Find the pdf of $Z$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I have random variables $X, Y, Z$, where

$X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda), Y \sim 
\text{Exp}(\mu),$ and $Z = X/Y$.

I calculated the PDF of $Z$ as

$$h(z) = \frac{\lambda\mu}{(\mu+\lambda z)^2}$$

Could you tell me if this is the PDF of a known distribution (like Beta, Gamma, ...) ?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be independent?

Comment: (scaled) Lomax distribution (a variate of Pareto distribution) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @BGM So $p(x) = \frac{\alpha\lambda^\alpha}{(z + \lambda)^{\alpha + 1}}$, where $\alpha := 1$ and $\lambda := mu$ ? This yields $\frac{\mu}{(z + \mu)^2}$ -- I could multiply this by $\lambda$, but then the $\lambda$ in the denominator would be lost? Or did I miss your point?


Thanks for your reply guys; By the way, could you quickly verify if I calculated the PDF correctly (as I did this with pen and paper...)

Comment: Yes you have figure out the parametrization in wiki. The next step is the reason why I put (scaled) in the previous comment. You can further scale it. E.g. when the pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x)$, we can use standard transformation technique to create a family of distribution with scale parameter - the pdf of $\frac {1} {\lambda}X$ is $\lambda f_X(\lambda x)$. The exponential distribution also has a scale parameter. You can try it.

Comment: It is also a [log-logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-logistic_distribution) with shape $\beta=1$ and scale $\alpha = \mu/\lambda$